# How to get correct typescript file and position information in Error.stack in Angular 6+

Tags: angular, typescript

This might be a duplicate, but I am going in circles when asking Google to get an answer to this question:

I run an Angular 7 application and when calling `const err = (new Error(""));`, `err.stack` contains a stacktrace that does not show up the correct Typescript source filenames and positions, instead it shows the positions in the webpack result (something like `main.js:582:42`).  However, the Chrome browser does show the right Typescript file names and positions in the console view.

FYI: Source map generation is enabled in angular.json.

I have fiddled around with the `source-map-support` npm-package but that does not work in the browser.

Any ideas how to get correct Typescript source filenames and positions in my `err.stack` stacktrace?